# Apex Chart only works when I resize my window size in angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, apexcharts, window-resize, asp.net-dynamic-data

Apex chart works fine with static data but when I pass data dynamically , It shows data only when the window is resized . The data from API are reaching perfect and there is no problem with it.

I have used this chart in angular help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.